# Explanation of the .eslint file

Tags: javascript, eslint

In the .eslintrc file I have something like:

```
"indent": [2, 2, {"SwitchCase": 1}],
```

That I understand. Numbers 2 on the right side determine the spaces.

But, considering this:

```
"no-alert": 2,
"no-else-return": 1,
"no-eq-null": 2,
"no-eval": 2,
"no-extend-native": 2,
"no-fallthrough": 2,    
"no-invalid-this": 2,
"no-lone-blocks": 2,
"no-loop-func": 2,
"no-multi-spaces": 2,
"keyword-spacing": 2,
"block-scoped-var": 2,
```

I am confused what does number 2 mean? It can't be spacing for all of it?

In this case:

```
"no-compare-neg-zero": "error",
```

that is self explanatory.

I have checked [eslint.org](https://eslint.org/), but could not find proper explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It defines severity of the rule.

```
0 = off, 1 = warning, 2 = error
```

You can read about them here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules